# The value of the column with data type of datetime always is 1970/01/01 in Java

Tags: java, date, jpa, epoch

Can someone please tell me why the value of my field in the database which has a data type of datetime always store the value 1970-01-01 no matter what value I input? Here is the code

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "date_received")
private Date dateReceived = new Date();
```

and this is the code I use to insert

```
@PostMapping("/createJrf")
public ResponseEntity<String> createJrf(@Valid @RequestBody JobRequirement req) {
    jrRepository.save(req);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Job Created", HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: Where do you input anything? 1/1/1970 is the value of a timestamp of 0 seconds. That likely means that the field in your database is null.

Comment: Have you checked the value in your `JobRequirement` object prior to the save?

Comment: I input the informations using postman like the ff.{
 "jobNumber": 22718,
 "phoneNumber": 639955838813,
 "dateReceived": "20180302",
 "company": "Boxchain",
 "position": "Messanger",
 "status": "On going",
 "oic": "Cedrix Emmanuel",
 "type": {
  "modelNumber": "AAA-001",
  "access": "none",
  "serialNumber": 45778134,
  "charges": 120000,
  "otherRemarks": "Ang tagal ko na naghihintay"
 },
 "equip": [{
   "equipmentName": "Macbook pro",
   "equipmentType": "Electrical"
  }],
 "equipcal": [{
  "deadLine": "20180304",
  "modeOfCalibration": "Rush"
 }]
}

Comment: is it because i am inserting the date the wrong way? by the way the dateReceived field is indeed null

Comment: @CedrixCedrix, adding more information is definitely welcome, just do it in the question itself rather than in comments, so we have everything in one place. Also I think that in the question you can format your postman input in a more readable way.

Comment: ok will do it next time @OleV.V. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved it was all in the format of my json in postman I was previously doing it as follows

"dateReceived": "20180302"

then I changed it to

"dateReceived": "2018-03-02"